# windows service as tier between code and webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-services

This might be a simple question, but is it possible to use a windows service as a tier between my code and a webservice?

I have a rather large project, and a webservice. Instead of calling the WS directly, I need a tier inbetween. (There are reasons to why that's a good idea...)

Since a windows service is all ready present, can I call that service, and get that same service to call the webservice?

Comment: You might need to explain more about exact requirements, because this looks a bit weird.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to make a call to a windows service, which makes a call to a webservice, which returns data to your windows service, which returns data to your original app.

Comment: Correct Mike. Sorry if the explanation was a bit off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [wcf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) to communicate with a windows service, that than communicates with a webservice.

Or you could host a web service in the windows service, that communicates with the original webservice.

That are just two examples, so it es technical possible to match you requirements.

Comment: About the first solution / example; Use WCF like creating a wcf service? So; Primary code -> wcf ws -> end ws?

Comment: Yes, your primary code will communicate to the windows service via wcf. The windows service then will communicate with the webservice. May be yout want to do it with the [proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern), so you can change your implementation to use the webservice directly if needed.

Comment: Think I got it. Thanks Chris :)